# Remove spaces between curly brackets with words javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, template-engine

I write a little function to inject pieces of templates to the HTML without the use of "big" templating engines like EJS, Mustache.js, Nunjucks, Pure.js, etc.

I pass this piece of code with a key-value object:

```
<div><b>@{firstname} @{lastname}</b>, @{gender}</div>
```

Now I need to remove the extra spaces if someone try to write "@{ firstname }" in place of "@{firstname}".

I'm sorry but I don't know how to write the right ReGex to remove the spaces. How can I remove the spaces?

Thanks for your support.

---

UPDATE:
Thanks to @Saleem for the answer. Here a demo with the fix: 
https://jsfiddle.net/avq3sntq/

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630). Use the regex only on the text nodes.

Comment: you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try following regex:

```
result = subject.replace(/(@\{)\s*(\S+)\s*(?=})/img, "$1$2");
```

If you input string is:

```
<div><b>@{ firstname } @{lastname}</b>, @{gender}</div>
```

Output will be:

```
<div><b>@{firstname} @{lastname}</b>, @{gender}</div>
```

As you can see, removes all extra spaces round firstname inside curly braces. See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV9eH6/1) here